# Biholomorphic function such that $\phi(0)=-2$, $\phi'(0)>0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $S=\mathbb{C}\, \backslash \,[{0,+\infty})$, $\mathbb{D}=\{{z:|z|\lt 1}\}$

Find a biholomorphic application $\phi:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow S$ such that $\phi(0)=-2$, $\phi'(0)>0$. Is it unique?

Could you please give me a hint on how to approach the problem? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first map $\mathbb{D}$ onto the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ by $\zeta=\varphi (z).$ Taking into account the condition $\phi(0)=-2,$ we choice $$ \zeta=\varphi (z)=-\sqrt{2}\,i\,\frac{z+1}{z-1},$$ which maps $\mathbb{D}$ onto $\mathbb{H}$ with $\varphi (0)=\sqrt{2}i$.
Next we consider $w=\psi(\zeta)=\zeta^2$. Of course it maps $\mathbb{H}$ onto $S$. Let $\phi (z)=\psi\circ\varphi(z)$, then $\phi$ maos $\mathbb{D}$ to $S$ and the condition $\phi(0)=-2$ is satisfied.
We check if $\phi^\prime(0)>0.$ Since $\phi^\prime(z)=\frac{8(z+1)}{(z-1)^3}$, we have $\phi^\prime(0)=-8$. Oops.
We try to change $\varphi (z)$ to $$
\varphi_1 (z)=\varphi (-z)=\sqrt{2}\,i\,\frac{1-z}{1+z}.
$$
Then we see that $$\phi (z)=\psi\circ\varphi_1(z)=-2\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)^2$$ satisfies $\phi^\prime(0)>0.$

Is it unique?
Yes, it is uniquely determined. If  there exists another $\phi_1(z)$ which maps $\mathbb{D}$ to $S$ with $\phi_1(0)=-2, \phi_1^\prime(0)>0$, then $\phi^{-1}\circ\phi_1$ maps $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$ and satisfies $(\phi^{-1}\circ\phi_1)(0)=0$ and $ (\phi^{-1}\circ\phi_1)^\prime (0)>0.$  We conclude that $\phi^{-1}\circ\phi_1(z)=z,$ which yields $\phi=\phi_1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for you comprehensive and clear answer. One of the difficulties I had was to find the mapping from $\mathbb{D}$ to S. I thought that applying $w=\psi(\zeta)=\zeta^2$ to $\mathbb{H}$ would also include the real positive axis $[0, +\infty)$, which we do not want.